# Hide public members from base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am implementing a custom MessageBox out of a form. The header of the class is pretty standard:

```
public partial class AutoClosingMessageWindow : Form
```

The class has the method:

```
public static DialogResult Show(...)
```

And I can call it similarly to the MessageBox -> AutoClosingMessageWindow.Show(...). The problem is I also see a lot of public members that come from Form and I'd prefer to "hide" them. I know in C++ you could have different types of inheritance but from what I researched you can't do that in C#.

Is there any way I could do this that doesn't imply reimplementing it in other ways just to avoid this?

Comment: using interface could give you more flexibility. learn: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703634/SOLID-architecture-principles-using-simple-Csharp

Comment: @CodeNotFound Hm so I can't basically :)

Comment: @Mr.Howell like Jon Skeet said in the answer to the linked question "You can't, basically."

Comment: @TazbirBhuiyan Interface? this actually made me realize I can just make another class and just open the window from there...

Comment: https://medium.com/@aaraashkhan/interface-driven-development-part-1-b7c7011860c0 learn about interface-based development. there will be situations when you won't be allowed to introduce a new class. As you come from c++. I will recommend you to read the first article I shared. it's very important as you are using a OOP language. the second one I shared in this comment might give you a general idea. So, follow the link of first comment at first. happy coding

Comment: @TazbirBhuiyan Alright, thanks I will look into this more because it's a good alternative. But the way I formulated the question I think it should also be marked as duplicate.